# How to properly implement MessageKit in swift 4? | Delegate functions are not being called

Tags: ios, swift, messagekit

I was trying to implement [**MessageKit**](https://github.com/MessageKit/MessageKit) (Replacement of JSQMessagesViewController) for chat feature, in my iOS swift application. I have followed this [**raywenderlich tutorial**](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5359-firebase-tutorial-real-time-chat). I installed using Pods and followed this tutorial step by step. My messages are showing. According to this tutorial, for hiding the user avatar, i set my viewController to be delegate of `messagesLayoutDelegate` and `messagesDisplayDelegate`.

```
//Inside view did load, i set the delegates, along with data source
messagesCollectionView.messagesDataSource = self
messagesCollectionView.messagesLayoutDelegate = self
messagesCollectionView.messagesDisplayDelegate = self
```

However, the delegate functions of `MessagesLayoutDelegate` are not being called.

I wanted to hide user avatar so i adopted the protocols in my viewController

```
extension ChatLogVC_MessageKit: MessagesLayoutDelegate {

 func avatarSize(for message: MessageType, at indexPath: IndexPath,
              in messagesCollectionView: MessagesCollectionView) -> CGSize {

    //return zero size for hiding avatar, but this function is not being called. 

  return .zero
 }

 func footerViewSize(for message: MessageType, at indexPath: IndexPath,
                      in messagesCollectionView: MessagesCollectionView) -> CGSize {

    //also not being called

    return CGSize(width: 0, height: 8)
 }

}
```

I have set break points inside these functions but the break points never hit. Morever, the `shouldDisplayHeader` function of `MessagesDisplayDelegate` is also not being called

Any help would be much appreciated

**Note: I have tested it on simulator only.**

Comment: https://www.scaledrone.com/blog/ios-chat-tutorial/

Answer (score 4):

Your delegate methods look outdated. If you are using Cocoa pods, at least use the 1.0.0 beta 1 version:

`pod 'MessageKit', '1.0.0-beta.1'`

Or, better, use the 1.0.0 version:

`pod 'MessageKit', '1.0.0'`

In your `viewDidLoad()` method set the delegate:

```
messagesCollectionView.messagesDataSource = self
messagesCollectionView.messagesLayoutDelegate = self
messagesCollectionView.messagesDisplayDelegate = self
messagesCollectionView.messageCellDelegate = self
```

By the way, the avatar size is set in the MessagesDisplayDelegate method `func configureAvatarView(_ avatarView: AvatarView, for message: MessageType, at indexPath: IndexPath, in messagesCollectionView: MessagesCollectionView)`.

Comment: a sample controller that uses MessageKit

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the Example in the Library

https://github.com/MessageKit/MessageKit/tree/master/Example